# Can't view aspx pages in Visual Studio 2010 Professional

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I have recently re-installed VS2010 Pro as I was having some problems with it. Since then I have had a problem. Everything seems to work fine however I cannot view any aspx page in VS. I have posted an example below.

[image: no aspx]

This happens on all aspx pages, however code behind pages are fine and I can also build, debug, publish etc with no problems. Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using AjaxControl Toolkit?

Comment: No however I am using the DevExpress AspXperience tools.

Comment: Have you looked at their docs? You may have to update your VS to the last SP and patches.

Comment: I haven't been able to find any information or similar problems on-line. I also have the latest versions of VS2010 and SP1 etc. I'm currently trying another re-install to see if this fixes the problem.

Comment: Well, that's a little naive but... have you restarted your PC?

Comment: Well considering I cannot find any information on-line, have no suggestions on here and have all the latest patches installed, restarted my machine, re-run the DevExpress installer tool and tried multiple times in VS to open it, I assumed it was probably my only option at the minute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that for me the solution was to re-install my version of Visual Studio.